# How to download a text data set from a website

Tags: r

I am interesting in a yeast dataset from UCI (please see the link). The data is saved in text formula. I would like to load it into Rstudio. I saved it in office word (copy and paste). Then, I tried to load it into R studio but I got unclear words instead of the data.

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Yeast

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grabbing the data is pretty easy; you can just pass the file URL directly to `read.table`. Getting the names is a lot more work, as they're buried in a text file. If you like, you can extract them with regex:

```r
library(tidyverse)

yeast <- read.table('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/yeast/yeast.data', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

l <- readLines('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/yeast/yeast.names')
l <- l[(grep('^7', l) + 1):(grep('^8', l) - 1)]
l <- l[grep('\\d\\..*:', l)]

names(yeast) <- make.names(c(sub('.*\\d\\.\\s+(.*):.*', '\\1', l), 'class'))

str(yeast)
#> 'data.frame':    1484 obs. of  10 variables:
#>  $ Sequence.Name: chr  "ADT1_YEAST" "ADT2_YEAST" "ADT3_YEAST" "AAR2_YEAST" ...
#>  $ mcg          : num  0.58 0.43 0.64 0.58 0.42 0.51 0.5 0.48 0.55 0.4 ...
#>  $ gvh          : num  0.61 0.67 0.62 0.44 0.44 0.4 0.54 0.45 0.5 0.39 ...
#>  $ alm          : num  0.47 0.48 0.49 0.57 0.48 0.56 0.48 0.59 0.66 0.6 ...
#>  $ mit          : num  0.13 0.27 0.15 0.13 0.54 0.17 0.65 0.2 0.36 0.15 ...
#>  $ erl          : num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
#>  $ pox          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ vac          : num  0.48 0.53 0.53 0.54 0.48 0.49 0.53 0.58 0.49 0.58 ...
#>  $ nuc          : num  0.22 0.22 0.22 0.22 0.22 0.22 0.22 0.34 0.22 0.3 ...
#>  $ class        : chr  "MIT" "MIT" "MIT" "NUC" ...
```

...or just copy them all out by hand.